# Keeping User-Input UITextVIew Content Constrained to Its Own Frame

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

Trying to create a large textbox of fixed size.

This problem is very similar to the 140 character constraint problem, but instead of stopping typing at 140 characters, I want to stop typing when the edge of the textView's frame is reached, instead of extending below into the abyss. Here is what I've got for the delegate method. Seems to always be off by a little bit. Any thoughts?

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
{
    BOOL edgeBump = NO;
    CGSize constraint = textView.frame.size;

    CGSize size = [[textView.text stringByAppendingString:text] sizeWithFont:textView.font 
                                                           constrainedToSize:constraint 
                                                               lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
    CGFloat height = size.height;

    if (height > textView.frame.size.height) {
        edgeBump = YES;
    }

    if([text isEqualToString:@"\b"]){
        return YES;
    } else if(edgeBump){
        NSLog(@"EDGEBUMP!");
        return NO;
    }   

    return YES;
}
```

EDIT: As per Max's suggestion below, here is the code that works (note, however, that autocorrect and cut do not work here):

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
{
    CGSize constraint = textView.frame.size;

    NSString *whatWasThereBefore = textView.text;

    textView.text = [textView.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:text];

    if (textView.contentSize.height >= constraint.height) {
        textView.text = whatWasThereBefore;
    }

    return NO;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem and noticed that  sizeWithFont   returns the wrong size. I used `yourTextView.contentSize`   instead. So you can add characters, obtain the content size and then delete newly added characters if content size is bigger then the maximum one.

Edit2: fixed

```
 - (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text {
    UITextView* clone_tv = [[[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame: textView.frame] autorelease];
    clone_tv.text = [textView.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:text];

    return (clone_tv.contentSize.height <= textView.frame.size.height*2);
}
```

Notice the clone_tv. We are actually changing the text in clone text view, and not in the real one. In this case autocorrect and cut works. However I recommend you to create some ivar named cloneTextView in your view controller and use it every time. Doing like this you will avoid unnecessary allocations.

Comment: Totally dumb  question, but I find that the contentView just keeps growing as more characters are added, so height never catches up. Thoughts?

Comment: you should always return NO from your  (textView:shouldChangeTextInRange:)  and set text manually.  If height >= max_height  ==>  yourTextView.text = text_before_adding_new;   Or maybe I misunderstood your question?

Comment: Wait, Max. Autocorrect doesn't appear to be working. Thoughts?

Comment: what do you mean 'Autocorrect doesn't appear to be working' ?

Comment: self.notesTextField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeYes;
does not appear to be functioning properly. This includes autocomplete suggestions and double tapping the spacebar to insert a period and capitalize the next letter. I think returning NO for - (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text disables this functionality, because returning YES fixes it again, but breaks the textbox limit.

Comment: re: edit. I think you need to flip the test condition, but otherwise works.

Comment: however cut operations no longer remove desired text.

Comment: you can handle cut operations separately. In that case range.length > 1

Comment: Would it be possible to modify your answer with the suggested solution that would enable cut?

Comment: Note that I had to add the clone_tv to an existing view in the controller (and hidden) in order for it to actually have its contentSize be resized by the system. (ios 6.1 simulator)